How do I upload artifacts with the github API or cli
I don't want to upload an artifact with the upload-artifact action. I want to use my own script to upload and download artifacts with my own code (python).
Why is there no "upload" method for artifacts in the docs? https://docs.github.com/en/rest/actions/artifacts?apiVersion=2022-11-28
How do I use the REST API or github cli to upload artifacts?

A bit of searching revealed the source of the actions code uploads artifacts via an RPC call to githubs internal API.
While you could reverse-engineer this, its very obvious that you are not meant to do this directly.
My recommendation: Use github actions, far better/easier to automate once you invest the time in my experience.

There is no published REST API. You can use @actions/artifact npm package.
